# Check if dataframe column value is present in list in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a Master of colors as a list below

```
master <- list("Beige" = c("light brown", "light golden", "skin"),
                      "off-white" = c("off white", "cream", "light cream", "dirty white"),
                      "Metallic" = c("steel","silver"),
                      "Multi-colored" = c("multi color", "mixed colors", "mix", "rainbow"),
                      "Purple" = c("lavender", "grape", "jam", "raisin", "plum", "magenta"),
                      "Red" = c("cranberry", "strawberry", "raspberry", "dark cherry", "cherry","rosered"),
                      "Turquoise" = c("aqua marine", "jade green"),
                      "Yellow" = c("fresh lime")
                     )
```

and this is the datframe column that i have

```
df$color <- c('multi color','purple','steel','metallic','off white','raisin','strawberry','magenta','skin','Beige','Jade Green','cream','multi-colored','offwhite','rosered',"light cream")
```

Now i want to check if value persent in `column` is same as `list key` or same as `list values`

**ex**:
1)if df column value is `off white` first it should look at list keys which are `Beige,off-white,Metallic...` if it is present than get the value
2)it should also look at all the values that those keys have like if one of keys value is `light cream` than it should be considered as `off-white`
3)no case sensitive matters like `OffWhITe == offwhite`  or space matters like `off white==offwhite`

**OUTPUT**
This should be the expected output

```
df$output <- c("Multi-colored","Purple","Metallic","Metallic","off-white","Purple","Red","Purple","Beige","Beige","Turquoise","off-white","Multi-colored","off-white","Red","off-white")
```

**EDIT**
any value in this `c("multi color", "mixed colors", "mix", "rainbow","multicolored","MultI-cOlored","multi-colored","MultiColORed","Multi-colored")` should be considered as `Multi-colored`

Comment: The output showed below may be different from the expected because your `master` list doesn't show all the elements .e.g for `Purple`, it is showed as `[1] "lavender" "grape"    "jam"      "raisin"   "plum"     "magenta"`. there is no matching element in 'purple'

Comment: ` "lavender" "grape"    "jam"      "raisin"   "plum"     "magenta"` if any of these values if present it should be considered as `purple`

Comment: yes, but if you look at the input, it is 'purple' for the second value which gets replaced by `Purple`

Comment: yes thats ok, but the the output that you provided below in that `Jade Green` doesn't get replaced by `Turquoise`

Comment: because it is a different `case` (`Jade Green` and `jade green`)

Comment: similarly `multi-colored` and `multi color` won't match because it is a fixed match with join

Comment: `case (Jade Green and jade green)` but in my question case sensitive should not matter  as i wrote in 3rd point `OffWhITe == offwhite`

Comment: It is not only the case sensitive, there are some cases where spaces are not there and replaced by `-` as in `multi-colored`.  Can you please verify the patterns needed to match

Comment: i have update the question with pattern that i can have

Comment: this looks like a `stringdist_right_join` or `regex_right_join` instead of `right_join` in my solution

Comment: Can you check the input and output.  How is `rosered` classified as 'Red' when your master `Red` doesn't have that option

Comment: Can you check my update.  It seems closer to your expected.  Now, the issue seems to be non-matching or non-existence of values in master

Comment: @akrun sorry that's a mistake..i am adding it

Comment: thanks, i updated the solution with the update you have

Comment: I had to upgrade my complete R system to `4.0.2` for `tibble`, and i think i was not able to make you understand in  `Metallic# [1] "steel"  "silver"` i want `df[4,] i.e metallic` to be checked with both `Metallic` and `"steel"  "silver"` so that would be `metallic == Metallic` hence `Metallic` appended in column, but still thanks for your effort i am upvoting your answer

Comment: Thanks, my point was that when you are doing the join, it is looking for the values in that 'key' `Metallic`.  so, if we add a new value 'metallic' in that master list, it would match

Comment: Yes, i  got this `looking for the values in that 'key' Metallic` point and i will update my data for your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can do a `string_dist_join` after `stack`ing the `list` into a single data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tibble)
enframe(master, value = 'color') %>%
      unnest(c(color)) %>% 
      type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
      stringdist_right_join(df %>%
             mutate(rn = row_number()), max_dist = 3) %>% 
      transmute(color = color.y, output = coalesce(name, color.y))
# A tibble: 19 x 2
#   color         output       
#   <chr>         <chr>        
# 1 multi color   Multi-colored
# 2 purple        purple       
# 3 steel         Metallic     
# 4 metallic      metallic     
# 5 off white     off-white    
# 6 raisin        Purple       
# 7 strawberry    Red          
# 8 strawberry    Red          
# 9 magenta       Purple       
#10 skin          Beige        
#11 skin          Multi-colored
#12 Beige         Beige        
#13 Jade Green    Turquoise    
#14 cream         off-white    
#15 cream         Purple       
#16 multi-colored Multi-colored
#17 offwhite      off-white    
#18 rosered       Red          
#19 light cream   off-white
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(color = c("multi color", "purple", "steel", "metallic", 
"off white", "raisin", "strawberry", "magenta", "skin", "Beige", 
"Jade Green", "cream", "multi-colored", "offwhite", "rosered", 
"light cream")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))
```

Comment: `dplyr` gives me this Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: Argument 2 must be type integer, not character and `enframe` gives me this `by` required, because the data sources have no common variablesTraceback:

Comment: @jamesjoyce can you check the type of joining columns i.e. i have both columns of the same type

Comment: `typeof(master)` is `list` and `typeof(df$color)` that i provided in my question is `character`

Comment: @jamesjoyce yes, the `master` `list` is converted to a 2 column dataset with `enframe` or `stack`

Comment: @jamesjoyce I added the `type.convert` in case it is showing issues for you

Comment: can you provide the complete data that you used, i am still getting this Error in UseMethod("mutate_"): no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: @jamesjoyce My data is already updated in my post under the `data` section

Comment: using your `data` and mine `master`.  Now,`dplyr` solution is working but i need it `not to be case sensitive` like `Jade Green == jade green` , and `enframe ` solution is still giving me `by required, because the data sources have no common variablesTraceback:`

Comment: @jamesjoyce the `enframe` issue could be a package version issue.  I use `packageVersion('tibble')#
[1] ‘3.0.3’` on `R 4.0.2`